# Molesting vs Groping

Tags: vocabulary

> *A man was seen using newspaper to hide his **groping** of a female commuter on the Shanghai metro recently.*

Can we use ***molesting*** instead of ***groping***?

Comment: Please include [more detail](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) with your question. What is your understanding of these terms? What makes you think one would be more fitting than the other? What makes you doubt that choice? What is the context? What are you trying to communicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days, certainly in the UK, the newspapers would probably go for a less-specific "indecent assault".

As tunny says, "molest" has a wider meaning.

Conversely, "grope" can invest the act with an unfortunate 1970's connotation, where it was almost socially acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *molesting* but, as you can see from this [dictionary definition](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/molest), *molest* has a wider meaning than [grope](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/grope) (definition 4).